# Trouble understanding problem regarding weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, $T\in B(X,Y)$ and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $X$. If $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ weakly show that $Tx_n\rightarrow Tx_0$ weakly.

I am pretty sure I have solved the problem, I am just confused exactly how I should understand the problem. I understood it as given that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$ for all $f\in X'$ then I have to show that $g(Tx_n)\rightarrow g(Tx_0)$ for all $g\in Y'$, is that correct? And in that case I believe I have done that.

I showed that for a given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $n > N$ we have that $|g(Tx_n)-g(Tx_0)|\leq\varepsilon$. I have done this by use of $x_n$ being weakly convergent to $x_0$ (I have done all the calculations and I am not unsure about those).

$\textbf{Here's the real question}$: When I asked my professor about my approach to this problem he said that it was a good idea, but that I needed to relate $g$ and $T$ to $f$ (in which he means $f\in X'$). That has been stumbling me for a bit, but I think I see what he means. Since $T$ maps $x\in X$ into $Y$ and $g$ maps $Y$ into $\mathbb{C}$ then $g(T)$ maps elements from $X$ into $\mathbb{C}$ thus one can see $g(T)$ as a bounded functional on $X'$ (bounded because $g$ and $T$ are bounded) and thus we have a bounded functional on $X'$ applied to the sequence $x_n$ in which we now know it approaches $x_0$ weakly thus $Tx_n\rightarrow Tx_0$ weakly. Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're still a little off.  $g \circ T$ (better notation) is a linear functional on $X$, not on $X'$.  That makes $g \circ T$ an *element* of $X'$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, I'm sorry, I meant it as it was a bounded functional in X' (but it acts on X) - I can see that the way I wrote it is misleading. Thank you for noticing that! Besides that, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  I think you could explain the last part a little more clearly: since $g \circ T$ is a bounded functional on $X$, we have $g(T(x_n)) \to g(T(x_0))$.  But $g \in Y'$ was arbitrary, so this shows $Tx_n \to Tx_0$ weakly.  By the way, $g \circ T$ is also known as $T^*g$ or $T' g$; this is how the adjoint $T' : Y' \to X'$ is defined.

Comment: You're right, your explanation is more clear. Thank you for the help, I've finally gotten all the pieces together and I understand it now!